# Regex expreesion for last update file

Tags: regex, logfile, date-comparison

Please help me out with a regex to find the last modified file/latest updated file in the folder.

The files are in this manner:

```
Test.2014_02_20 updated 13:00:23
Test.2014_02_21 updated 15:23:23
Test.2014_02_25 updated 21:24:23
```

Using regex we need to pick up the file `Test.2014_02_25 updated 21:24:23`

Thanks.

Comment: `'#(Test.\d+_\d+_\d+ updated \d+:\d+:\d+)#'`

Comment: You can use regexs to validate the format of the line, but I don't think you can compare data with regexs only.

Comment: Regular Expressions do some pattern-matching, but the concept of ordering things by some criteria is way out of the scope of regex. So to make it short: you can't do this using regex - although you could try to extract the date and time parts via regex and process these within your program...

Comment: Thank you all. I am new to stack overflow, pls let me know if u have some kinda kudos or likes that can be given to the comments posted in response to the question.

Comment: @user3351366 Simply mark your choosed answer as accepted ;) See here for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through the comments from @Theox and @piet.t, OP has concluded that regular expressions were not the best tool to accomplish the task here.

> *"You can use regexs to validate the format of the line (...)"* - [Theox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2273184/theox)
>
> *"(...) the concept of ordering things by some criteria is way out of the scope of regex"* - [piet.t](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2664350/piet-t)